# How to call DrawThemeTextEx in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, api, pinvoke, aero

I need to write a text with glow in a Vista/seven glass window, and I'm, trying to call the API to write some text there. I have checked out a great [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/textonglass.aspx) in CodeProject, but the problem is that I'm using .NET 1 (please, don't ask :-)

I need to translate the follwing .NET 2 code  to PInvoke, .NET 1 code.

```
// using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles
VisualStyleRenderer renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(
                               VisualStyleElement.Window.Caption.Active);

// call to UxTheme.dll
DrawThemeTextEx(renderer.Handle, 
                memoryHdc, 0, 0, text, -1, (int)flags,    
                ref textBounds, ref dttOpts);
```

The class `VisualStyleRenderer` does not exist in .NET 1, so I need to get the `renderer.Handle` in other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the OpenThemeData API and DrawThemeTextEx, as well as some required structs and constants:

```
    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenThemeData(IntPtr hwnd, string pszClassList);

    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private extern static Int32 DrawThemeTextEx(IntPtr hTheme, IntPtr hdc, int iPartId, int iStateId, string pszText, int iCharCount, uint flags, ref RECT rect, ref DTTOPTS poptions);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct DTTOPTS
    {
      public int dwSize;
      public int dwFlags;
      public int crText;
      public int crBorder;
      public int crShadow;
      public int iTextShadowType;
      public int ptShadowOffsetX;
      public int ptShadowOffsetY;
      public int iBorderSize;
      public int iFontPropId;
      public int iColorPropId;
      public int iStateId;
      public bool fApplyOverlay;
      public int iGlowSize;
      public IntPtr pfnDrawTextCallback;
      public IntPtr lParam;
    }

    // taken from vsstyle.h
    private const int WP_CAPTION = 1;
    private const int CS_ACTIVE = 1;
```

And then, call it like this:

```
IntPtr handle = OpenThemeData(IntPtr.Zero, "WINDOW");
DrawThemeTextExt(handle, hdc, WS_CAPTION, CS_ACTIVE, ...)
```

The WS_CAPTION and CS_ACTIVE values match .NET 2's Caption and Active respectively. Values are described here officially: [Parts and States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773210.aspx)

Comment: Word of caution to whoever wants to use this code. It has a memory leak. The author used Win32 APIs that require release of the `handle` via `CloseThemeData` API call.

Comment: @ahmd0 - Of course, the Windows API is not "managed" and in general you have to release what you acquire. If you read carefully, this code doesn't even compile and is nothing but complete. This is sample code, not production code. You should also check the return value of OpenThemeData, and the return value of DrawThemeTextExt.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you get what you want by calling [`OpenThemeData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759821%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

To work out all the details it would be much easier for you to write a sample app in C++ to get to know how to drive the theme API from the ground up.  There are many tutorials and lots of sample code on the web.  But do it in C++ where you will have all the functions readily available. The last thing you want to get doing is fighting with P/Invokes whilst you are also getting to grips with low-level theme API.

Once you get it cracked in C++, then move on to the P/Invokes and if you have trouble it will be easy to refer back to the C++ code  that works.