# Create label with the same properties as the title

Tags: c#, wpf, glow

Note how the letters of the title of my window glow:

[image]

How could I create a label with the same effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF you can overlay ordinary text on text with a blur to accomplish the background glow effect.

Here's the markup:

```
<Grid Background="CadetBlue">
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <TextBlock Text="Stack Overflow" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="AliceBlue">
            <TextBlock.Effect>
                <BlurEffect Radius="30"/>
            </TextBlock.Effect>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Stack Overflow" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and this is what it looks like:

[image: Text Glow Effect]

Answer (score 0):

[You want to use DrawThemeTextEx.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461937/how-to-call-drawthemetextex-in-net/5465756#5465756)